# (Facebook) Workplace from Meta API - Get data from Achievement post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I am trying to get all the data from an achievement post, like the title, the message, the image and the tagged people, but I am only able to get the message.

Any idea how can I get the rest of the information, especially the title?

Comment: Did you _ask_ for the fields you are interested in? `/{post-id}?fields=...,...`

Comment: Yes, I think I checked all the fields. I put metadata=1 to discover the fields and then manually I added the fields in the URL. But almost all are empty.